# Can messages consume automatically from Rabbit MQ in .net 8

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I am implementing the RabbitMq messing queue in .Net8 I had written individual methods to publish and consume the messages from the queue. is there any possibility to  automatically consume the messages after publishing without writing a method?

I tried below logic in a method but I need to consume messages automatically.

```
using (var connection = _rabbitMqManager.GetConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
 channel.ExchangeDeclare(_exchangeName, ExchangeType.Direct);
 channel.QueueDeclare(_queueName, true, false, false);
 channel.QueueBind(_queueName, _exchangeName, _queueName);

 var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
 consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
 {
   var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
   var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
   Console.WriteLine($"Received: {message}");                
 };

 channel.BasicConsume(_queueName, true, consumer);
}
```